# File permissions resetting with git pull

Tags: linux, git

On Linux, whenever I perform a `git pull` on a directory, all of the files lose their permissions that I have set for them. How do I keep this from happening?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2517339/1030675

Comment: Hope the link given below will help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/12735291